# Centering Website Content + Vertical Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, centering, margins

I'm trying to center the main content of my page with a vertical navigation on the right side of the page. For smaller screen resolutions, there's no problem. However, for widths above 1400px, the content seems aligned to the left.

For the CSS I just have:

```
margin-left: 200px;
```

However, most of the time I use the following to center content:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

For the media queries, I simply eliminate the margin as the navbar will hide itself.

```
@media (max-width: 995px) {
.game_card, .game_card2, .footer_wrapper, .footer_legal {
margin-left: 0px;
 }
}
```

** Can't post image due to lack of reputation pts so a link is below **
https://ibb.co/eqJMF8

Comment: Did you try `margin: 0 auto` for `@media (max-width: 995px){ }` ?

Comment: When I do that, the main elements stay 200px to the right. (I set that initial 200px left margin because of the sidebar menu.

Comment: At the moment, the website displays fine on smaller screens -- just not on larger desktops. Here's the image -->  https://ibb.co/eqJMF8

Answer (score 1):

Try setting margin:0 auto; to your css. It should be centered on all screen sizes.

Also, check [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) out. It helped me a lot when I was struggling with this not that long ago.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can center things fine without the navbar on the left. Making custom media queries for all content is going to be a pain -- but there must be a way to take the 200px on the left screen into account.